# Ubuntu Unison: filter everything except multiple files

Tags: unison

I want to synchronize two computers that are similar and update just a few files. Therefore I would like to perform a Unison and ignore everything except a list of files in different paths.

Something like:

```
# /usr/bin/unison-gtk /home/ ssh://root@192.168.0.199:22//home/ -ignore "Name *" -ignorenot "Name {config/text.cfg, Pictures/test.jpg, Desktop/test.mp3"
```

Or even better starting with root directory:

```
# /usr/bin/unison-gtk / ssh://root@192.168.0.199:22// -ignore "Name *" -ignorenot "Name {/home/config/text.cfg, /home/Pictures/test.jpg, /usr/local/bin/test.sh"
```

The first ignore is exclude everything else so the ignorenot won't catch them. Any Help? Can anyone help? Nothing I have found is helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `-path` option for unison instead of `-ignore`?  From the [unison manual and reference guide](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) section **Using Unison for All Your Files**

> tell Unison to synchronize only some of the files and subdirectories within it on any given run. This can be accomplished by using the -path switch on the command line: ... The -path option can be used as many times as needed, to synchronize several files or subdirectories:

Here is a quick practical example.

- create `local` and `remote` directories (the `remote` directory is a stand-in for an actually remote directory in this case).

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir local remote
```

- create 9 files in the `local` directory.

```
root@ubuntu:~# for i in $(seq 9); do uuidgen > local/${i}.txt ; done
root@ubuntu:~# ls local
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt
```

- use `unison` to sync the files, but limit the sync to the files named `1.txt`, `2.txt`, and `3.txt`.

```
root@ubuntu:~# unison -auto -batch local/ remote/ -path 1.txt -path 2.txt -path 3.txt
Contacting server...
Looking for changes
...
Reconciling changes
file     ---->            1.txt
file     ---->            2.txt
file     ---->            3.txt
...
```

- confirm the `remote` directory only contains those files.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls remote/
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

Things get more interesting when content changes.

- Create the same files in the `remote` directory.  This will update the synced files and create new files for the unsynced.

```
root@ubuntu:~# for i in $(seq 9); do uuidgen > remote/${i}.txt ; done
```

- use `unison` to sync the directories again

```
root@ubuntu:~# unison -auto -batch local/ remote/ -path 1.txt -path 2.txt -path 3.txt
Contacting server...
Looking for changes
Reconciling changes
         <---- changed    1.txt
         <---- changed    2.txt
         <---- changed    3.txt
...
```

- the synced files (e.g. `1.txt`) content will match in both directories.  The unsynced files (e.g. `9.txt`) content will be different.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat {local,remote}/1.txt
7317d9ef-9747-43ae-9f4c-347fc4134e65
7317d9ef-9747-43ae-9f4c-347fc4134e65
root@ubuntu:~# cat {local,remote}/9.txt
76654fcf-d0b2-4788-8a84-b765c9a41cc3
f5db8eb3-4300-463a-9d49-fcb14afcae12
```